# Using mogenerator with Swift 2.0

Tags: swift2, mogenerator

I tried to use mogenerator with `--swift` on swift 2.0 project. But it is not generating proper code to handle relationships. Any one got a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mogenerator working on a update for swift 2.0

[Issue #302](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/issues/302)

For me it is not fully ready for production use for swift 2.0. 
I would generate usual objc for model (Using objc code in swift project is so common) and use swift extension if you want to beneficial from new swift features. I know this way you got to deal with 5 files per one model.